# Grails: Query on the class type of an association

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, instanceof

I have a domain model object (let's call it MainObject) that has another object in it (let's call it SubObject).  However, the SubObject can be one of a few classes derived from the same main SubObject class.  How can I query and find all the MainObjects that have a SubObject of a specific class type?  It's sort of like doing a "instanceof" call in a query.

Comment: Are you using a table per hierarchy? Some example domain classes would be helpful.

Comment: No, I'm actually using a table per class.  That means that doing an actual SQL query to figure this out is no problem ... I'm just not sure how to do it using Grails/Hibernate.

Comment: Oddly I'm not finding much information about how to accomplish this, but from the Hibernate documentation it seems the general idea is to implement your own "marker" on each sub class and use that as a discriminator in your query.

Comment: I can put together a quick example as an answer if that helps.

Comment: That's what I thought I'd have to do as a last resort ... I guess it will be my first resort :)